# Cannot start MySQL server after new installation on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7-x64

I know this is a common problem and there are many potential solutions. I have tried everything I can find. I still cannot start the server.

I am using Windows 7.
I have installed mysql using the MSI for version 8.0.16.0.

I followed the steps and ran the default and opened workbench.

Workbench says NO CONNECTION.

I went to find the server and start it. I see no directory for this in the installation. So I download the zip of the server in order to run it manually. I open it and run mysqld.

The first error I get: Can't create test file computer.lower-test. It's not a permissions issue. I consider authorisation and run it as admin. No change. I consider the password issue. I run mysql_secure_installation.exe but that requires the password. I look for how else to reset the password. I see I must check the error log. There is no error log (or at least I cannot find it).

Now I am stumped :(

Comment: mysql workbench didn't work under windows 7 and i guess that also true for the engine. But you should check if the sevice is startet and check also windows event viewer. But i think change your Os or install an older Version of mysql

Comment: yeah it wasn't running already and i did used to have it all working on here before... years ago. i think I'll have to find an older version.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing some versions of this: Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable